# What should be considered in terms of non-linearity as a percentage of f.s.d?

Tags: sensors

A thermocouple used between 0 and 500 °C has the following input–output characteristics:

[image]

(a) Find the equation of the ideal straight line.

$$
K = \frac{27388 \hspace{1mm} \mu V} {500 \hspace{1mm} ^\circ C}
\approx 54.776
$$

$$
a = 0 \hspace{1mm} \mu V
$$

$$
O(I) = 54.776 I
$$

(b) Find the non-linearity at 100 °C and 300 °C in µV and as a percentage of
f.s.d.

$$
N(I) = O(I) - KI
$$

[image]

The largest non-linearity has been shown in red number in the table above

$$
\frac{\hat{N}} {O_{max} - O_{min}}
=
\frac{209.06 \hspace{1mm} \mu V} {(10777 - 5268) \hspace{1mm} \mu V}
\approx 3.8\%
$$

Some choose to argue that $O_{max}$ is 27388 and $O_{min}$ is 0. But I think we only consider the output of 100 and 300 Celsius degrees according to the question.

Please share what you think of this.

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly the question is.

Comment: @Chris_abc What do you think $O_{max}$ and $O_{min}$ are?

Comment: But what is your question?  This is not a discussion board, so what we think of it, is irrelevant and off topic.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Is my answer correct?